# How should I reference two tables with a single foreign key?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a Company model and I have a Customer model. Both can be a relation.

```
type Customer struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title string
}

type Company struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title string
}

type Relation struct {
    gorm.Model
    CustomerOrCompanyID uint
}
```

So both are a relation. How can I have my relation pointing back to either the company or customer?

Comment: just to make it clear, you want to load from `companies` or `customers` tables, based on lead type, into the `Lead` model? Do you have `LeadType`and `LeadID` fields in those tables?

Comment: No I have not right now. So I can just add a LeadID / Type to the other tables and use a foreign key?

Comment: one more question, is that just for loading the data into the `Lead` model, or for all CRUD operations?

Comment: I have seperate crud operation for customers and companies. I only want to get a company or customer based on the leadID

Comment: I'm not really sure if it's possible to do it with one gorm query. If two queries are OK,  and you have `lead_id` and `lead_type` columns in both `companies` and `customers` tables, you can try it with https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#Smart-Select-Fields

Comment: How would you know if the ID in `CustomerOrCompanyID` is a customer ID or a company ID? Do you have some boolean field saying this is a customer or not? Or does the ID itself contain that information? Like `cust-1234` and `comp-1234`?

Comment: @TehSphinX I did think about that but I left it in the open so it could be a point of discussion. I really don't know what my approach should be to this problem. But using a boolean is certainly a option, I just thought that this might be a naive solution

Comment: @MikeOttink: See my answer below. Even from a pure SQL perspective, I'd use 2 columns as it makes things a lot easier with e.g. a query that contains the main table `Relation` and data from both `Customer` and `Company`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to do this naturally in Gorm using a polymorphic Has One relationship. This will enable you to easily run some of the queries that @TheSphinX has provided.

You will however need to add a type discriminator column to your relation table in order to make it work:

```golang
type Customer struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title string
    Rel   Relation `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner"`
}

type Company struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title string
    Rel   Relation `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner"`
}

type Relation struct {
    gorm.Model
    Foo       string
    OwnerID   uint
    OwnerType string
}
```

Now you create records normally:

```golang
cust := Customer{
    Title: "Cust",
    Rel:   Relation{Foo: "bar"},
}
comp := Company{
    Title: "Comp",
    Rel:   Relation{Foo: "baz"},
}
db.Create(&cust)
db.Create(&comp)
```

To run a query that gets either Customer or Company with the related information as in @TehSphinX's first two queries you'd do something like:

```golang
var cust Customer
db.Joins("Rel").First(&cust, 1)
```

The last query would be more complex, but can also be done with a custom row struct and joins:

```golang
var rows []struct {
    Relation
    Customer Customer `gorm:"embedded;embeddedPrefix:cust_"`
    Company  Company  `gorm:"embedded;embeddedPrefix:comp_"`
}

db.Select(`
        relations.*,
        customers.id AS cust_id,
        customers.title AS cust_title,
        companies.id AS comp_id,
        companies.title AS comp_title
    `).
    Model(&Relation{}).
    Joins("LEFT JOIN customers ON relations.owner_id = customers.id AND relations.owner_type = 'customers'").
    Joins("LEFT JOIN companies ON relations.owner_id = companies.id AND relations.owner_type = 'companies'").
    Find(&rows)

// now rows[i].Relation is filled, and rows[i].Customer or rows[i].Company 
// are non-zero depending on rows[i].Relation.OwnerType
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: speaking from a pure SQL point of perspective, since I haven't worked with `gorm` yet:

In my comment above I asked:

> How would you know if the ID in `CustomerOrCompanyID` is a customer ID or a company ID? Do you have some boolean field saying this is a customer or not? Or does the ID itself contain that information? Like `cust-1234` and `comp-1234`?

Since you need a way to distinguish what kind of ID is in `CustomerOrCompanyID` anyway, I'd suggest to have two fields: `CustomerID` and `CompanyID`. One of them is always `0` (or `NULL`).

That way you know which table to join in and can also join in both at the same time depending on what data type each row has, the columns for the customer or the company will be filled.

---

I think `gorm` should not have a problem anymore if there are 2 fields as it would handle each of them as a normal relation that is not set for all columns.

---

Some example SQL statements (MySQL Dialekt):

All customers:

```sql
SELECT 
    Relation.ID as RelID, Relation.OtherColumn,
    Customer.ID, Customer.Name
    /* etc. */
FROM 
    Relation INNER JOIN Customer ON (Relation.CustomerID=Customer.ID);
```

All companies:

```sql
SELECT 
    Relation.ID as RelID, Relation.OtherColumn, 
    Company.ID, Company.Name
    /* etc. */
FROM 
    Relation INNER JOIN Company ON (Relation.CompanyID=Company.ID);
```

You might also want all data in `Relation` with the columns of Company and Customer and decide in the frontend which ones to use:

```sql
SELECT 
    Relation.ID as RelID, 
    Relation.OtherColumn, 
    Customer.ID as CustID,
    Customer.Name as CustName,
    Company.ID as CompID,
    Company.Name as CompName,
    /* etc. */
FROM 
    Relation 
    LEFT JOIN Company ON (Relation.CompanyID=Company.ID)
    LEFT JOIN Customer ON (Relation.CustomerID=Customer.ID);
```